# laptop keyboard some keys don't work for a while but later on work

Tags: windows-10, laptop, keyboard, sleep

Very wierd issue.

Clean install of windows 10 home.
After leaving the computer for a while, sometimes some keys on the keyboard don't work. Some specific examples: 8, 9 right arrow, down arrow.

This typically happens after waking the machine from sleep.

What I found was if i open notepad and start mashing keys the nonfunctioning keys (i.e. not destructively hitting them, but quickly repeatedly pressing them) they will start working again, and won't fail till the computer goes back to sleep.

Nothing has ever been spilled on keyboard.
possible related issue, computer won't fall asleep by itself now. e.g in power management I've set the computer to sleep after 30 minutes when plugged in but it never does. It still auto sleeps if on battery, and i can command it to sleep from start menu or closing lid.

I've scoured the internet for what the root cause might be, but not much luck.
Things i've tried:

- changed power management settings. don't even remember what
  specifically now because so many.
- uninstalled all keyboard drivers and rebooted for them to be reinstalled.
- run the powercfg command which resulted in changing a setting in power management to disable wake on network (or something like that))

Anyone know how to solve or how i can further troubleshoot?

Answer (score 0):

I would try hooking up a USB keyboard to see if you experience the same issue.

If the same happens with an external keyboard then you can assume it is a software issue.

If the external keyboard works as expected I would assume hardware failure -- most likely a short somewhere in the keyboard. This would make since as you're have keys going out in bulk which are next to each other.

You can find replacement laptop keyboards on eBay or Amazon for usually less than $20.